# Python threading structure

Tags: python, multithreading, daemon

I read some code like that.

```
def bind():
    while True:
        line = raw_input()
        #do something

def worker():
    print "i'm working"
    #do something

th = threading.Thread(target=worker)
th.daemon = True 
th.start()
time.sleep(0.5)
bind()
```

What does worker mean? why not use

```
th = threading.Thread(target=bind)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you want to ask why worker is used as a daemon thread but not bind.

A daemon thread means that the entire Python program exits when only daemon threads are left.

Function worker is set as a daemon thread. Here it means no matter whether function worker is done, once function bind return, function worker will terminate immediately.

[Here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html) are some instructions for daemon. Check section 16.2.1.  Hope it helps.

Comment: What functions is correspond to daemon? init function or main function?

Comment: @huythang There is no init function in the code. main function is the main process. threading.Thread starts a new thread in the code and th.daemon sets this new thread as a daemon. In this new daemon thread, function worker is running.

Comment: @huythang If there is no more questions, don't forget to accept it as an answer. Thanks!